# RDP randomly slows to a crawl (not tcp autotuning)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, windows-xp, rdc

Most of the time my RDC works perfectly.  Sometimes it slows to a complete crawl and I cannot even get my mouse clicks to register on the remote computer.  The client computer is Windows XP, so there's no chance of it being a tcp autotuning issue (not introduced until Vista AFAIK).  I also get "session ended" messages randomly.

Here's the computer specs -

Client computer

- Windows XP Pro SP3
- RDC 6.0
- Core Duo T2600 (2.16 ghz)
- 2 GB memory
- 5Mbps download, 500 Kbps upload

Sever computer

- Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1 (x64)
- Core i7 3.07 ghz
- 12 GB memory
- 2 Mbps download, 5 Mbps upload

I've tried tuning down all settings (resolution, colors, etc) to no success.  I can communicate in other ways with the server (FTP, HTTP, etc) when its slow over RDC with no problems at all.

Answer (score 1):

RDP is much more sensitive to network conditions then FTP or HTTP are. When the problem is occurring I would suggest running a network capture on the client and the server and look for the following:

1. A large volume of broadcast traffic, at layers 2 and/or 3
2. A large volume of TCP retransmits
3. Latency between the client and the server
4. Packet loss between the client and the server

Comment: Can you recommend a good tool to use for this?  I do not have experience with this kind of network analysis.

Comment: Wireshark, Colasoft Capsa, Microsoft Network Monitor.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, I was able to use a workaround for awhile.  I have time now to actually solve the problem.  I ran Wireshark, set it to filter for the TCP stream with the RDC connection and it picked up tons of "Bad TCP" traffic as it calls it.  How should I go about analyzing the problem and solving it?